Ubuntu 22.04 LTS to 24.04 LTS upgrade FAILED
I upgraded my 22.04 LTS system to 24.04.
EDITED.
sudo do-release-upgrade -d

... Lots of output...

The upgrade failed
libglib-perl:amd64

libqt5qmlmodels5:amd64

gnome-control-center

libkf5i18n5:amd64

libkf5parts5:amd64

qml-module-qtquick-controls2:amd64

libqgpgme15t64:amd64

ksudoku

Processing was halted because there were too many errors.

Upgrade complete

The upgrade has completed but there were errors during the upgrade process.

To continue please press [ENTER]


I then did a reboot which also failed with numerous FAILED messages (OCR so won't be completely accurate).
Is there a way to overwrite the system files from the USB installer so that I can preserve my install?
I've seen numerous questions but nothing that actually answers my exact problem.
FWIW, the system hangs after the last error message and all I can do is power off.
[ 1.416504] ioremap error for ox3dadd000-0x3dade000, requested 0x2, got 0x0

[FAILED] Falled to start bolt service Thunderbolt system service.

[

FAILED] Failed to start bluetooth service- Bluetooth service,

[ [

FAILED] Failed to start power-profiles-daemon.service FAILED] Falled to start cups service CUPS Scheduler, Power Profiles daemon

[ [

FAILED] Failed to start libvirtd.service libvirt legacy monolithic daemon, FAILED] Failed to start NetworkManager.service Network Manager,

[FATLED] Falled to start cups.service CUPS Scheduler. [FAILED Failed to start bolt.service- bolt service Th Thunderbolt system service,

[ [

FAILED Failed to start libvirtd.service - libvirt legacy monolithic daemon

FATLED] Falled to start power-profiles-daemon.service Power Profiles daemon

[FATLED] Falled to start NetworkManager.service [ Network Manager.

FAILED Failed to start bluetooth.service Bluetooth service.

[FAILED Failed to start cups.service CUPS Scheduler.

FATUEL Failed to start libvirtd.service libvirt legacy monolithic daemon

[FATLED

Failed to start bolt.service Thunderbolt system service.

[FATLEI

] Failed to start NetworkManager.service Network Manager. FAILED) Failed to start cups.path CUPS Scheduler.

[

[FAILED Failed to listen on cups.socket CUPS Scheduler.

[DEPEND] Dependency failed for cups.service CUPS Scheduler. [FATLED Failed to start libvirtd.service libvirt legacy monolithic daemon...

[FAILED Failed to start power-profiles-daemon.service Power Profiles daemon

[

FATLE Failed to start bluetooth.service Bluetooth service.

[

FATLEI] Failed to start power-profiles-daemon.service Power Profiles daemon

[

FAILED Failed to start bolt.service Thunderbolt system service. FAILED Failed to start bolt.service Thunderbolt system service.

IFATLED Failed to start bluetooth.service Bluetooth service. to start bolt.service Thunderbolt system service.

IFATLET] Failed

[FAILED Failed to start bluetooth, service - Bluetooth service.

[FAILED Failed to start gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager.

IFAILED Failed to start gdm, service GNOME Display Manager,

[

FAILED] Failed to start colord, service Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles

FAILED] Failed to start gdm,service GNOME Display Manager, [




When you did the actual update process did it indicate a failure or no?  Usually I see these failures when your system needs to undergo a filesystem check because your drive is in an inconsistent state (in which case you need to boot to a LiveUSB and run fsck on the disk that holds your Ubuntu installation)

@ThomasWard yes. ```Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
Upgrade complete```
